# How to get a SQL table with Kafka?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka

I want to view the results of a query in SQL with Kafka (Confluent 5.4.0, with Kafka 2.12).

I try using Kafka JDBC connector (using the mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre8 driver and Java 8u201) first with these parameters:

```
{
  "name": "sqlview",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "tasks.max": "10",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=testDB",
  "connection.user": "testUser",
  "connection.password": "password",
  "mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
  "incrementing.column.name": "ID",
  "timestamp.column.name": "CREACIONDATE",
  "query": "select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.CDATE ASC) AS ID, t1.CDATE as CREACIONDATE, t1.NAME, t2.CRITICALITY, t3.DESCRIPTION, t4.USER, COALESCE(t5.name, 'None') as task from WORKSPACE w inner join TABLE1 t1 on w.IDWORKSPACE = t1.IDWORKSPACE inner join TABLE2 t2 on t1.IDASSET = t2.IDASSET inner join TABLE3 t3 on t2.IDASSET = t3.IDASSET inner join TABLE4 t4 on t2.IDUSER = t4.IDUSER inner join TABLE5 t5 on t2.IDASSET = t5.IDASSET",
  "topic.prefix": "conceptTest"
}
```

But Kafka cannot create the topic and the Kafka Connect log say the next error message:

> ERROR Failed to run query for table
>   TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table=null, query='select
>   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.CDATE ASC) AS ID, t1.CDATE as
>   CREACIONDATE, t1.NAME, t2.CRITICALITY, t3.DESCRIPTION, t4.USER,
>   COALESCE(t5.name, 'None') as task from WORKSPACE w inner join TABLE1
>   t1 on w.IDWORKSPACE = t1.IDWORKSPACE inner join TABLE2 t2 on
>   t1.IDASSET = t2.IDASSET inner join TABLE3 t3 on t2.IDASSET =
>   t3.IDASSET inner join TABLE4 t4 on t2.IDUSER = t4.IDUSER inner join
>   TABLE5 t5 on t2.IDASSET = t5.IDASSET', topicPrefix='conceptTest',
>   incrementingColumn='ID', timestampColumns=[CREACIONDATE]}: {}
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:337)
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name
>   'CREACIONDATE'.   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1624)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:594)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:446)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.executeQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:178)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TableQuerier.java:92)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:61)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:315)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Then change the parameters for this:

```
{
  "name": "sqlview",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "tasks.max": "10",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=testDB",
  "connection.user": "testUser",
  "connection.password": "password",
  "mode": "incrementing",
  "incrementing.column.name": "ID",
  "query": "select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.CDATE ASC) AS ID, t1.CDATE as CREACIONDATE, t1.NAME, t2.CRITICALITY, t3.DESCRIPTION, t4.USER, COALESCE(t5.name, 'None') as task from WORKSPACE w inner join TABLE1 t1 on w.IDWORKSPACE = t1.IDWORKSPACE inner join TABLE2 t2 on t1.IDASSET = t2.IDASSET inner join TABLE3 t3 on t2.IDASSET = t3.IDASSET inner join TABLE4 t4 on t2.IDUSER = t4.IDUSER inner join TABLE5 t5 on t2.IDASSET = t5.IDASSET",
  "topic.prefix": "conceptTest"
}
```

Again, Kafka cannot create the topic and the log show me the next message:

> ERROR Failed to run query for table
>   TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table=null, query='select
>   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.CDATE ASC) AS ID, t1.CDATE as
>   CREACIONDATE, t1.NAME, t2.CRITICALITY, t3.DESCRIPTION, t4.USER,
>   COALESCE(t5.name, 'None') as task from WORKSPACE w inner join TABLE1
>   t1 on w.IDWORKSPACE = t1.IDWORKSPACE inner join TABLE2 t2 on
>   t1.IDASSET = t2.IDASSET inner join TABLE3 t3 on t2.IDASSET =
>   t3.IDASSET inner join TABLE4 t4 on t2.IDUSER = t4.IDUSER inner join
>   TABLE5 t5 on t2.IDASSET = t5.IDASSET', topicPrefix='conceptTest',
>   incrementingColumn='ID', timestampColumns=[]}: {}
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:337)
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name
>   'ID'.     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1624)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:594)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:446)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.executeQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:178)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TableQuerier.java:92)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:61)
>     at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:315)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Finally, I change the increment mode to bulk, with these parameters:

```
{
  "name": "sqlview",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "tasks.max": "10",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=testDB",
  "connection.user": "testUser",
  "connection.password": "password",
  "mode": "incrementing",
  "query": "select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.CDATE ASC) AS ID, t1.CDATE as CREACIONDATE, t1.NAME, t2.CRITICALITY, t3.DESCRIPTION, t4.USER, COALESCE(t5.name, 'None') as task from WORKSPACE w inner join TABLE1 t1 on w.IDWORKSPACE = t1.IDWORKSPACE inner join TABLE2 t2 on t1.IDASSET = t2.IDASSET inner join TABLE3 t3 on t2.IDASSET = t3.IDASSET inner join TABLE4 t4 on t2.IDUSER = t4.IDUSER inner join TABLE5 t5 on t2.IDASSET = t5.IDASSET",
  "topic.prefix": "conceptTest"
}
```

And then, Kafka can create the topic, but the data is repeated for every pool (I need the data without duplicates), then this "solution" doesn't work.

Then how to get the query results with Kafka?